# Build a regular grammar for L = {x∈{0,1}∗|x is the binary encoding of a number divisible by 4}

Tags: grammar, regular-language

Using the symbols 0,1 and using binary for numbers divisible by 4, i.e 100,1000,1100,10000,10100,11000,111000,100000

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I guess by divisible you mean "divisible with a zero reminder with allowed leading zeroes". The regular grammar (left-regular) for this is:

```
S = A0
A = B0
B = B0
B = B1
B = ε
```

The idea is that in the **end** of the input there must be **two** zeroes, because the binary numbers that are divisible by **four** have **two** zeroes at their less significant bits.

If you disallow the leading zeroes then you get that (that implies and non-zero input; right-regular grammar):

```
S = 1A
A = 0A
A = 1A
A = 0D
D = 0
```

With ABNF grammar:

```
S = "1" *("0" / "1") "0" "0"
```

And regular expression:

```
^1[01]*00$
```

Comment: You missed a case - 0 is divisible by 4.

Comment: I wrote that first, but by the input it seems that the zero is not included. By the question it is. It also boils down to are the leading zeroes allowed or not (is the minimum possible representation implied by the example input or not). I have let the possibility to have and leading zeroes.

Comment: I was not critical enough. Thank you for the notes. I have to respectfully disagree, that "the" and "is" are enough to determine the leading zeroes. For this reason I have let both.

Comment: Well, I'm no native English speaker, but I think with proper English usage, saying "the" does mean there's only *one* (encoding of the number). And allowing leading zeros means there are infinitely many, so one wouldn't say "the". And like I said, their list also suggests no leading zeros. But yeah, my main wish was for the no-leading-zeros solution to have a more prominent place, and now with your much improved answer, it has.

Comment: As far as I know, "the" is used when the object is priory known. The given language, accepts leading zeroes. I would let that for now, till the user have questions.